# how to get csv string from a specific column

Tags: php, mysql

column `src` is like this:

```
imga.jpg
imgb.jpg
imgc.jpg
```

I need to get two variables:

```
$firstimg = 'imga.jpg';
$images = 'imga.jpg,imgb.jpg,imgc.jpg';
```

In my try there is no problem with `$firstimg` but cannot get `$images`

```
$ids = '1,2,3';
$st = $db->query("select src from images where id in (" . $ids . ") order by field (id, " . $ids . ")");
$images = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$firstimg = $images[0]['src'];
$images = implode(',', $images['src']);  // error - undefined index `src`
```

Comment: How do you expect the first value be accessed via `$images[0]['src']` but the others via `$images['src']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have array of `src`: `[["src" => "imga.jpg"], ["src" => "imgb.jpg"]...]`

You can do this:

```
$images = implode(',', array_column($images, 'src'));
```